# How to access Person or Group column in REST API Url

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to access Person or Group column using REST API, but it is giving an error "BAD URL". Can someone please help me with this ?

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Plan')/getitems?$select=WRNo
```

Here WRNo is a person or group column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it per item:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Plan')/items(<id of item>)?$select=WRNo/Title&$expand=WRNo/Id
```

or all:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Plan')/items?$select=WRNo/Title&$expand=WRNo/Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand People or Group column to get the details associated with that column.

**Get all items**

```
 https://site-url/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/Items?$expand=WRNo&$select= WRNo/Title
```

**Get specific item**

```
https://site-url/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/Items(ItemID)?$expand=WRNo&$select= WRNo/Title
```

Where WRNo is the Person column Internal name.

Below are some available values other than Title to get from Person column with REST :

Title

Name

EMail

MobilePhone

SipAddress

Department

JobTitle

FirstName

LastName

WorkPhone

UserName

Office

ID

Modified

Created

ImnName

NameWithPicture

NameWithPictureAndDetails

ContentTypeDisp

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should use it like this

```
http://yourSite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Title,Id,Author/Title&$expand=Author
```

use expand to select people ou lookup fields

[an example here](http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/sharepointrestquerylist.html)

Comment: OP is clearly specify field WRNO as person or group. So you should reply in that manner